# Connecting to SSH server slow since macOS upgrade

Tags: ssh

Since upgrading to macOS I have had problems with slow connection to my local server running Debian.

Running ssh -v shows that it is hanging at the following message.

> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

A search has said try to enable the NoDNS option within the servers sshd config but that has not helped.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I realize you are probably meaning Sierra, but Apple is rebranding the entire OS X line as macOS, from El Capitan backwards. So please specify which version of macOS you upgraded to.

Comment: @tubedogg Did Apple rename OS X to macOS for for all previous versions, up to El Capitan, or just starting with Sierra?  I've read some tech sites indicate the name was rebranded but nothing from Apple (who still indicate "OS X El Capitan" on their sites).  Just curious.

Comment: @fsb ["Put down a Mavericks partition on a Mac with Sierra, and Startup Disk will tell you that you've installed 'macOS 10.9.5.'"](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/09/macos-10-12-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/2/#h2) See e.g. [Printer and scanner software for macOS Sierra, El Capitan, Yosemite ...](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465) on Apple's site - "OS X" is not found on that page. I have a feeling that macOS will replace OS X as they update articles, similar to how the change happened gradually over the course of the Sierra betas.

Comment: That said I have also seen pages where they say "macOS Sierra and OS X El Capitan" so who knows.

Comment: @tubedogg Thanks for the info and sorry, xreyuk, for the temporary hijack of your question.

Comment: I have the same issue here. Since the last macos update (to Sierra), connecting via ssh is really slow. I used to do CFD post-processing from home on my workstation at work, now it is no longer possible. I'm trying to figure out what happened...

Answer (score 2):

I tracked down my slow SSH logins to IPv6 timeouts. This was from a Sierra client to a Sierra server. After adding the following to my client `~/.ssh/config` it is now near instantaneous.

```
# Default is 'any' which includes inet6
AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I'm running a Sierra client to a Debian server.

Comment: Ah that's too bad. The other suggestion I saw when trying to track down my problem was to use disable `GSSAPIKeyExchange` on the client.