# Can I change the size of my applications folder icons from the dock?

Tags: macos, applications, dock, icon

[image]

I have included a picture. 
My applications folder is on the dock and when I click on it the applications come up but the icon size is too big, is there anyway to make these icons a lot smaller? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hey guys , Thanks a lot for your responses  !! Command & + , Command & -    can make the icons bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the size on the Applications Dock menu in Grid view click the Applications Dock Tile and then press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to make the menu and icons smaller or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to make the menu and icons larger.

I have tested this under **OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5**, **OS X El Capitan 10.11.6** and macOS Sierra 10.12.

The image below is from **OS X El Capitan 10.11.6** taken on a Thunderbolt Display at 2560 x 1440 and of three separate screen shots that were cropped from the lower right corner to the size necessary to show the size of each grid menu and its size changed and layered to reduce the size of posting 3 individual images. Nothing has been retouched, just cropped and layered to contrast between a large menu in the back, the default size menu on this Display in the middle and a smaller sized menu up front. Calculator.app was used to show scale and as you can plainly see the size of the icons changes with the size of the grid menu.

[image: Application Dock Menu in Grid view]

Comment: This still works in Monterey (macOS 12.1) in 2022 :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the size of the icons in the grid itself (the keyboard shortcut that worked in macOS Lion no longer does), but you can change it to list view by right-clicking on the folder icon and selecting List. This will result in a list similar to a Finder view, with much smaller icons.

Edit: After further testing, the commands that I said no longer worked from Lion actually do work, at least in my testing in macOS El Capitan 10.11.6. They did not work initially, and when they finally did start working it took several seconds for anything to happen, though now they seem to be working ok.

They are:
<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> to make them larger, and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> to shrink them.

Comment: theres noting i can do with terminal. There has to be something i can code or change values of how big the icons can be ...??

Comment: @user3439894 Apple has retroactively changed OS X to macOS. See the comments on [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255837) for further details.

Comment: @JessicaRam Nothing I found indicated this is set in any way that is user-modifiable, no. I'd guess there's a zoom percentage set by the system based on how many icons are present.

Comment: @tubedogg, Apple has not retroactively changed anything! The only version of macOS presently is macOS Sierra 10.12, Previously releases of Apple's Desktop OS version 10.8 through 10.11 are OS X and 10.0 through 10.7 are Mac OS X! All you have to do is look at About This Mac and the only Apple Desktop OS that shows macOS is Sierra and not anything else! All others either say OS X or if old enough Mac OS X!

Comment: @user3439894 Whoa, buddy, take a breath. I'm sorry you don't like what Apple is doing. Do not edit my post again, though.

Comment: Also, for the record, they [retroactively changed Mac OS X Lion to OS X Lion](https://www.engadget.com/2012/02/16/apple-drops-the-mac-from-os-x-lion-mountain-lion/).

Comment: @tubedogg, I just booted an old MBP, which is running **Mac OS X Lion 10.7**, and clicked the **Apple** menu then [**About This Mac**](http://imgur.com/APtjftX). It clearly, plainly, explicitly and specifically shows it as **Mac OS X 10.7** and that is exactly what it is! **NOT** macOS Lion as you erroneously and ludicrously seem to think that it is. At the present time, the only macOS is macOS Sierra 10.12. It seems your reality distortion field is stronger then what Steve Jobs was!

Comment: @user3439894 I'm shocked, _shocked_ I tell you, to hear that they didn't issue software patches for _six-year-old software_ to change the name. I never claimed that they did that. What I did state, backed up by [actual screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/H8cGs) and [Apple's](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205081) own [support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465) articles, is that they are referring to all versions of 10.x as macOS. I'm not sure why you're having such a hard time accepting this. [Others](http://tinyurl.com/zntf6lb) aren't.

Comment: @tubedogg, Did you even look at the bottom of those Apple links, it clearly says OS X Maverick, OS X El Capitan, OS X Mountain Lion, macOS Sierra and OS X Yosemite on one and the other except OS X Mountain Lion is left off of that article. Apple doesn't have a magic wand that that can retroactively renamed previous products. The products exist as they are! My OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 says OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 not macOS 10.11.6 on About This Mac.

Comment: @user3439894 Apple can do whatever the hell they want. _They are their products_. And I do see the text at the bottom of the page. Clearly they haven't finished updating stuff. [This page](http://tinyurl.com/jf6mueh) is completely unambiguous, though. Oh, and [this one](http://tinyurl.com/gt39oph). [This is an actual marketing page showing it](http://tinyurl.com/grztjkq) (look at the footnotes). Heck, here are the [Google results](http://tinyurl.com/hz4hqav) including lots of Mac App Store listings referring to it that way, which Apple wouldn't allow if they weren't on board with it.

Comment: @tubedogg, Real nice update, to your originally wrong answer, you just copied from my answer. And don't edit my post again!

Comment: @user3439894 My originally mistaken answer stated the _the keyboard shortcut that worked in macOS Lion no longer does_. Clearly I knew about the shortcuts or I could not have made that statement. But, thanks for trying.